# Did anyone ever possess all three Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling, deathly-hallows

In the Harry Potter universe; was there anyone who ever possessed all three (Elder Wand, Resurrection Stone, *the* Invisibility Cloak) Hallows at once?

This is barring the creator / creators (Death or the Peverell brothers).

I know that Dumbledore was in possession of the Elder Wand, and also the Invisibility cloak (borrowed it from James) and then later the Elder Wand and the Stone; but never all three at the same time.

Is this the closest anyone has gotten? or **Has anyone ever been in possession of all three Hallows?**

Books, Interviews and Wikia sources preferred.

**Edit:**
Since I originally did not consider "possessing" and "ownership" I will keep the original meaning.

Comment: Harry did, kind of, for most of book 7. Granted he didn't have the wand in his hand, but it was his...

Comment: I like this comment. Please put into answer.

Comment: @BorhanMooz - I think if you're going to count items that are *in absentia* -- like Harry and the wand in book 7, which is a great concept, no doubt -- it's only fair that you edit your question to not include the words "possess" or "possession" because they mean to have on one's self or in one's immediate property. Just a suggestion. :)

Comment: Yeah, when I originally wrote the question, I was mainly thinking of actual "possession", and I might edit the question to reflect that. It just struck me as interesting what @PearsonArtPhoto said, since Harry was the Master of the Elder Wand without actually having "possession" of it...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Dumbledore was in possession of all three Hallows; however, not at the same time. He got the Elder Wand from dueling Grindelwald. He borrowed the Invisibility Cloak from James Potter to "examine it", but James was killed before Dumbledore could return it. Dumbledore subsequently returned the cloak to Harry in *Philosopher's Stone* ("Use it well.") for Christmas. He retrieves the Resurrection Stone from the Gaunts' cottage (I believe) during the summer between Harry's fifth and sixth year. In trying to put on the ring containing the Resurrection Stone, Dumbledore received a lethal curse that Snape was able to temporarily control.

So, yes, Dumbledore. I see that you noted this in your question, but as far as I know, there isn't any other character who possessed the three Hallows either all together or separately.

Comment: "as far as I know, there isn't any other character who possessed the three Hallows either all together or separately." What about Harry? He had the cloak for years, the stone for a year (though he only knew it for a few minutes), and the wand for some time.  He was also the only one who used the stone properly, and if you count him owning/controlling the wand without direct possession, he owned all three at once.

Comment: @Kevin I think Harry did suspect that the Golden Snitch had the Resurrection Stone for a while, but couldn't prove it because he didn't know how to open the Snitch.  I'm not completely sure about this though, I'll have to check the book.

Comment: I remembered right.  Harry already suspects that the Stone is in the Snitch in *Deathly Hallows* chapter 22, not long after he learns of the story of the Hallows.

Answer (score 39):

Harry was in possession of all of the Hallows at some point in time, as was Dumbledore. Harry arguably owned all of them for most of Book 7. He had the cloak and the stone inside of the snitch, although he didn't know it until near the end of the book, and he owned the wand, although he didn't know it, nor did he have it for most of the book.   He did briefly physically have the wand as well, but that was after he had dropped the Resurrection Stone. Bottom line, Harry was the closest to mastering all of the Deathly Hallows that is mentioned in the books, with Dumbledore as a close second.

Comment: Dumbledore did not own them all simultaneously. He gave the cloak to Harry long before obtaining the stone!

Comment: An excellent answer. Harry was the closest to having all three at any given time, if you count 'in absentia'.

Comment: Harry did suspect that he had the Resurrection Stone in the Snitch early, starting from *Deathly Hallows* chapter 22.

Answer (score 3):

I realise this might be a stretch - and I debated whether it should just be a comment, but I would run into the character limit, since reasoning might take a bit:

Technically Dumbledore **was** in possession of all three Hallows at the same time once, or at least almost, again depending on the definitions of *ownership* and *possession*.
In German legal speak there is the term of *"mittelbarer Besitz"*, which - according to Wang, German Civil Code, London 1907 - translates to *"indirect possession"*. Kind of like if you walk a dog, and it wears a collar, you indirectly possess the collar.

Thinking about this led me to the following conclusion:

When Dumbledore collected Harry from Privet Drive before Harry's 6th year (in HBP) and they side-alonged, Dumbledore was *indirectly in possession* of The Cloak, which Harry was carrying (i.e. owning and *"directly possessing"*) while being *carried/dragged-along* by Dumbledore, who wore the recently retrieved Resurrection Stone to impress Slughorn and of course also still carried, therefore possessed (and owned) the Elder Wand.

> "[...] However, I would like you to bring your Invisibility Cloak… just in case.”
>   Harry extracted his cloak from his trunk [...] stuffed it into an inside pocket of his jacket, Dumbiedore waved his wand [...] **--HBP, Ch.3 - Will and Won't**

At the very least, we can be reasonably certain that this was probably the closest together physically the three Hallows were since their creation: Harry extracts the cloak from his trunk while Dumbledore wears the Ring and wields the Wand. That is the only point in the story I can recall when all of them would be visible to an observer at the same time. Which they were never again afterwards (at least until someone finds the Stone in the Forest, steals the Wand from the Tomb (again) and steals the Cloak from whoever will then own it, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The Resurrection Stone and the Cloak of Invisibility were handed down the generations of descendants of Cadmus Peverell and Ignotus Peverell, respectively. So regardless of who was in possession of the Elder Wand, the other two Deathly Hallows were separated.

#### Albus Dumbledore

Dumbledore gained possession of the Elder Wand after defeating Grindelwald in 1945. He borrowed the Cloak of Invisibility from James Potter somewhere after 1980 and handed it over to Harry Potter in 1991. He retrieved the Resurrection Stone in the late '90s.
So he never had the three Deathly Hallows in his possession *at the same time*.

#### Harry Potter

Harry received the Cloak of Invisibility from Dumbledore in 1991. After disarming Draco Malfoy in 1998, the Elder Wand considered him its master, although he didn't have it in his possession at that time. Dumbledore had left him the Resurrection Stone in his will, although Harry only found it about it much later. During the Battle of Hogwarts, he retrieved the Stone from the snitch, but left it in the forest shortly afterwards.
After defeating Voldemort, the Elder Wand came in his possession, but that was after having left the Resurrection Stone in the forest.
So while he was the *owner or master* of all three Deathly Hallows at the same time, he didn't have all three of them *on his person* at the same time.

The Resurrection Stone was lost in the forest and the Elder Wand is in Dumbledore's tomb, so *for now*, there's no other wizard in possession of all three Deathly Hallows.

Answer (score -3):

Dumbledore had them all but not at one time. He owned the elder wand and resurrection stone but borrowed the invisibility cloak.

Comment: The question specifically asks about posession, not ownership.

Comment: hello and welcome to scifi&fantasy SE, please refrain from using the answers to add details about a question or an answer, and when posting one try to be as precise as possible and back your answer with proofs. Enjoy your stay, cheers!